# apachebench aborts with a strange error message

Tags: apache, apache2, benchmarking

I run a very simple php file on apache. Then I benchmark apache, using

```
ab -n 10000 -c 5  http://localhost/~me/hello.php?name=Niko
```

But I get this error message, depending on c (for c=1, things are fine):

```
apr_socket_connect(): Operation already in progress (37)
```

I'm using ApacheBench, Version 2.3  on OSX 10.5.7.

The very simple PHP file would be this one:

```
<h1>Hello <?=$_REQUEST['name']?></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be connected with http://www.nabble.com/ab(1)-fix-(Operation-already-in-progress-(37))-td22821642.html.

This might be it. The post says:

> fixed in trunk
>
> Changes were significant, so I have no
>   plans to propose for backport to the
>   2.2.x branch in the short term.  With some testing/everyday use in trunk on
>   various platforms, it may be
>   appropriate to backport later.

Well. That means I would have to wait for 2.3 or work straight with the trunk. I'm just doing hobby stuff, so: no thanks.

Comment: Here's how it looked back then: https://web.archive.org/web/20090704122143/http://www.nabble.com/ab(1)-fix-(Operation-already-in-progress-(37))-td22821642.html